# Error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) When you using emojis with googletrans discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

So I'm getting this error When i use imojies in discord eg, `t-tr es :smile:`
But without the emojis it works fine for example `t-tr es Hello` outputs `Hola` which is right but `t-tr es :smile:` should output  but gives error instead!

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def tr(ctx,des,*,msg):
    m=translator.translate(msg, dest=des)
    await client.say(m.text)
```

Comment: How on earth do you expect it to translate an emoji :)??

Comment: It should not translate it, it should leave it as it is eg, :smile: Do you know a way i can atleast make it that if a word starts and ends with `:` it should leave it?

Comment: Could you write down the error that appears, please?

Comment: Yup, that I can do... You can remove any words that start and end with colon `:` using regular expression like this one `:\w+:`

Comment: The error i get is `Error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`